# KeystoneJS 6 with NextJS 13. Image Upload to Local Storage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo, keystonejs

### The app

- backend [keystone](https://keystonejs.com/) server
- frontend [next](https://nextjs.org/) app
- using [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/) to work GraphQL magic.

It's an ecommerce store where the client can do all CRUD application in the NextJS app.

### The Problem

Uploading an image to **Keystone's** local storage (through the NextJS app) is tough.

### My Code

`CreateProduct.tsx`

```
import useForm from "@/lib/useForm"
import { gql, useMutation } from "@apollo/client"
import ErrorMessage from "../ErrorMessage"


export const ProductCreate = () => {

  const {inputs, handleChange, clearForm, resetForm} = useForm({
    image: '',
    name: 'new product',
    price: 123,
  })
  
  const [createProduct, {loading, error, data}] = useMutation(
    CREATE_PRODUCT_MUTATION, 
    {variables: {data: {
      photo: {
        create: {
          altText: `${inputs.name} featured image`,
          image: {upload: inputs.image}           //** HERE IS THE ERROR
        },
      },
      name: inputs.name,
      price: inputs.price,
      description: inputs.description,
    }}}
  )

  async function handleSubmit(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(inputs);
    const res = await createProduct()
    console.log(res);
    
  }


  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <label htmlFor="image">
          Image
          <input required type="file" id="image" name="image" 
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>

      ...folded

    </form>
  )
}


const CREATE_PRODUCT_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation CreateProduct($data: ProductCreateInput!) {
    createProduct(data: $data) {
      name
      photo {
        altText
        id
        image {
          extension
          filesize
          height
          id
          url
          width
        }
      }
      id
      description
      price
      status
    }
  }
`
```

### Error

```bash
Unhandled Runtime Error
ApolloError: Variable "$data" got invalid value {} at "data.photo.create.image.upload"; Upload value invalid.
```

### What I tried

- https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-discussions-archive/discussions/54#discussioncomment-120169 has a solution, but it's outdated
- i tinkered around with [apollo-upload-client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/file-uploads/#:%7E:text=Apollo%20Client%20doesn%27t%20support%20a%20file%20upload%20feature,for%20file%20upload%20can%20be%20found%20here%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fjaydenseric%2Fapollo-upload-client.) but I don't fully understand how to get it to play nice with Keystone.